# Heat content in a body

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

Suppose I have 1 kg of water at 25°C, is there a way (or equation) to find out the heat content in it?
Sure there is a similar equation:
$Q=mc\Delta t$,
where $m$ is mass,
$c$ is specific heat,
$\Delta t$ is the change in temperature,
and $Q$ is the amount of heat added (or removed).
The above equation shows the amount of heat added when the body is taken from temperature $t_1$ to $t_2$ (as already obvious by looking at the '$\Delta$' sign present in the equation).
And this equation does not show the heat content present in a body at stationary temperature, so what/which equation does?

Comment: I first read this as "human body"... was going to write about the metabolism generating about 100 watts in steady state. If this cannot be dissipated, temperature goes up about 1 degree per hour leading to heatstroke. Or if metabolism stops, temperature goes down about 1 degree per hour.

Comment: That comment is completely irrelevant to the question. I would remove it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the body (or anything else) does not “contain “ heat. Heat is energy transfer between things due solely to temperature difference.

What the body does contain is internal energy. A measure of the kinetic energy component of its internal energy is its temperature.

The body regulates its temperature within a narrow range around 98.6 F. If exposed to extreme cold it may experience hypothermia which the Mayo Clinic defines as body temperature less than 95 F. If exposed to high temperatures as in summer it may suffer from hypothermia or heat stroke which the Mayo Clinic defines as body temperature in excess of 104 F.

Because it regulates its temperature the use of  $Q=mC\Delta T$ Is not suitable means of determining heat transfer to or from the body.

Comment: The question never mentions a human body, it is clearly referring to a body of mass. Therefore your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Like Pieter I read this to mean a human body. Since two of us independently read it the same way, I suspect others would also. In any case the first two paragraphs always  apply. The rest applies in the case of a human body

Comment: "Heat is energy transfer between things due solely to temperature difference." Not necessarily. This does not hold when the thermoelectric effect is taken into account, for example. The heat flux is worth $\vec J_Q = ST\vec J-\kappa \nabla T$.  The first term on the right hand side deals with the thermoelectric effect. If you neglect it, you indeed get a relationship between the heat flux and the thermal gradient, or temperature difference across different regions if you prefer. But it isn't the first time I mention this to you, at this point I feel you do not buy the lesson and so this

Comment: comment is mostly for anyone interested to know the truth. What the equation shows is that you can induce/have a heat transfer even though the whole material is isothermal, no temperature difference anywhere (you can impose this condition). The way to accomplish this is by using an electric current.

Comment: @AccidentalBismuthTransform: You might be correct about the thermoelectric effect, but your point really isn't relevant IMHO. OP is using heat, temperature and internal interchangeably. It's a mistake which is, sadly, very common on physics.stackechange. It's much more important to address this fundamental misconception than to nitpick about the thermoelectric effect. "Heat is energy transfer between things due solely to temperature difference" is good enough for many readers, and it's 1000 times better than mixing up heat and internal energy.

Comment: @EricDuminil Thanks for that.

Comment: @EricDuminil I fully agree with your comment. I hoped Bob D would write something like it. But I am very glad he seems to agree with your comment too. Yes, thinking of heat as a state variable is the big mistake that should be addressed (and was correctly addressed by Bob D). I wish I could remove my downvote to this answer, but stack exchange system is so stupid that I cannot do that unless the post is modified. (as if giving an upvote or downvote meant that we cannot change our mind afterwards unless the post itself is changed... holy hell.)

Comment: I have edited the post, so that I can remove my downvote. Done. Sorry @BobD.

Comment: @AccidentalBismuthTransform No problem, and thanks for the reconsideration.  I also have had a desire to reverse a down vote but was unable to unless there was an edit. A shortcoming of the site, IMO. But like you I made a minor edit to as a "work around".